# Client specific project in jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

My question is how to create client specific projects in JIRA cloud, so that clients can't view company's internal project and are restricted to their own project view in JIRA?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to configure:

- [User Groups](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-groups-802592332.html)
- [Project Roles](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-project-roles-802592463.html)
- [Project Permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-project-permissions-802592442.html)

Typically your customer users are part of a *customers* group. Your internal users are part of other groups, e.g. *internal*.

Within a project you have different roles. You can assign groups to a role, ie. *customers* can have the *users* role in the project that is relevant to them. Your internal people can for example be in the *developers* role of projects that are relevant to them.

In a project's permission scheme, you then configure which permissions correspond to each role. If you assign the *browse* permission to the *users* role, and the *customers* group has that role, then they will be able to view the issues in that project.

If you don't put the *customers* group in a role then they won't be able to see or do anything with the issues in that project.